# How can I save dataURL to a mysqli database not through the URL?

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I want to save a dataURL generated from a HTML5 canvas to a MYSQLI database.  Everything I am finding is telling me to post it in the URL and then handle it on the next page.  The dataURL is to long for that as I have other things as well, and in the future I want to save a JSON string to the same MYSQLI database and definitely can't pass it in the URL, it will be way to long.  What do I do for both the JSON and the dataURL when i'm using PHP and MYSQLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to know how to do this all you would do is pass the data with ajax!